# Transposing multiple pandas columns while keeping duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to transpose or transform the following data frame:

```
chr    start1    end1    start2    end2    sample_id
chr1      111      222      333    444     id1
chr1      555      666      777    888     id1
chr2      989      999      111    112     id1
chr2      777      663      332    112     id1
```

into the following data frame:

```
chr    start    end   sample_id
chr1    111     222   id1
chr1    333     444   id1
chr1    555     666   id1
chr1    777     888   id1
chr2    989     999   id1
chr2    111     112   id1
```

I have attempted using pandas melt and append methods but both weren't a success, is there a way to do this using Pandas?

Here is my attempt using pandas.melt:

```
merge_coordinates = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['chrom', 'sample_id'], value_vars ['start1', 'end1', 'start2', 'end2'])
```

With using append: it was partially successful but I don't know how to associate other columns (chr, sample_id) and append them with the newly created one:

```
start = df['start1'].append(df['start2']).reset_index(drop=True)
end = df['end1'].append(df['end2']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df=df.reset_index()
```

Finally use `wide_to_long()`:

```
out=(pd.wide_to_long(df,['start','end'],i=['index','chr','sample_id'],j='idx')
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates(['index','chr','sample_id','idx'])
   .drop(['index','idx'],1))
```

### Update:

since the above solution is not working for you so here is the alternate solution:

```
df=df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[0:-1] if x[-1].isnumeric() else x)
out=df.melt(['chr','sample_id']).reset_index()
```

Finally:

```
out=(out.pivot(['index','chr','sample_id'],'variable','value')
        .agg(sorted,key=pd.isnull)
        .dropna()
        .reset_index(level=[1,2])
        .rename_axis(index=None,columns=None))
```

output of `out`:

```
    chr     sample_id   start   end
0   chr1    id1         111     222
1   chr1    id1         333     444
2   chr1    id1         555     666
3   chr1    id1         777     888
4   chr2    id1         989     999
5   chr2    id1         111     112
6   chr2    id1         777     663
7   chr2    id1         332     112
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got an empty table. Can you please elaborate more on your approach ?

Comment: @aBiologist updated answer...added output..btw is your index start with 0 in your actual dataframe and after reseting index check the names of columns?

Comment: @aBiologist Since the previous solution wasn't working for you due to any reasons......Updated answer with an alternative solution....Kindly have a look ***:)***